# Identify duplicates in a List print by sequence

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList, a Collection class of Java, as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
animals.add("bat");
animals.add("owl");
animals.add("bat");
animals.add("bat");
```

In the  above animals list, each unique animal name should be ordered together along with occurrence number. 
Eg:bat name occurs  3 time, 
Owl name occurs 1 time. 
expected output should be :

```
1:bat
2:bat
3:bat                                                                                                                                               
1:owl
```

Can anyone help me to do coding in java

Comment: Whats your code?

Comment: Please update your question instead of writing a comment with your code scrunched up in it

Comment: I'm not sure why the comment with the OP's streams code was removed without adding its content to the question. Please add the code from that comment to the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get the output you want from the `Map` you generated.

```
Map<String, Long> counts =
    animals.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
counts.forEach((k, v) -> LongStream.range(1,v+1).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + ":" + k)));
```

EDIT: due to `Collectors.counting()` returning `Long`, I had to switch to `LongStream`.

If you prefer, you can work with `Integer`s as follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts =
    animals.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.summingInt(s -> 1)));
counts.forEach((k, v) -> IntStream.range(1,v+1).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + ":" + k)));
```

Either way, the output is:

```
1:bat
2:bat
3:bat
1:owl
```